# how to have 2 divs side by side with position relative

Tags: html, css

I am building a site that requires 6 images side by side and when you hover each image you should be able to see a larger image.

Currently I have managed to write the following code that shows 2 images with the hover feature. The problem I have is that the images appear on top of each rather than side by side. I have tried adding a float:left but then the 2nd image doesn't show up the hover image and I am not sure how I can fix this.

The following is the HTML and CSS:

```css
.Enlarge {
  position: relative;
}
.Enlarge span {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}
.Enlarge span img {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
div.Enlarge:hover {
  z-index: 999;
  cursor: pointer;
}
div.Enlarge:hover span {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 240px;
  height: 340px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Enlarge">
  <img src="image1.jpg" alt="" /><span><img src="image1h.jpg" alt="" /></span>
</div>
<div class="Enlarge">
  <img src="image2.jpg" alt="" /><span><img src="image2h.jpg" alt="" /></span>
</div>
```

Would appreciate it if somebody could advise on how I can fix this, as I need to show 6 images but at present tried with 2 images to make sure it works.

Comment: what is your error?

Comment: The only thing you did to the `.Enlarge` divs is give them `position: relative`. That's not gonna help, and neither is all that styling for the spans *inside* the divs.

Comment: Divs naturally add lines breaks before and after because their default is `display:block`. Just add `display:inline-block` to `.Enlarge`

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at my jsfiddle i just used style="float: left"

```
<div class="Enlarge" style="float: left">
  <img src="image1.jpg" alt="" /><span><img src="image1h.jpg" alt="" /></span>
</div>
<div class="Enlarge" style="float: left">
  <img src="image2.jpg" alt="" /><span><img src="image2h.jpg" alt="" /></span>
</div>
```

Edit: it was missing the link https://jsfiddle.net/m4odfrcr/

Comment: Thanks Antonio, forgot to add the link

Answer (score 0):

modify your class as below

```
.Enlarge {
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys, that brings the images side by side but now the 2nd image doesn't show the hover image. When they are on top of each other it works but not side by side...